# How to check if 3 fingers are placed on a non-Surface control?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pixelsense

I already asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173691/how-to-check-if-3-fingers-are-placed-on-the-screen). This works fine for Surface controls, but how can I check the number of contacts on non-Surface controls like for example a Canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contacts.GetContactsOver( element )